# Cost of ingress controller in aks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I am planning to implement an ingress controller in aks

[image]

I know there are options like Nginx and API gateway.

How I can choose one over another.

I am implementing this for reducing my number of load balancers.

[image]

So hopefully cost will be less for the ingress controller compared to the load balancer.

Where I can estimate the cost of ingress controllers?
I need to setup same number of paths of number of load balancers currently (like 20 load balancers)

Answer (score 0):

You will only expose the Ingress Controller Service with one LoadBalancer. Then your costs are 1 LoadBalancer and 1 Public IP.

This is done via this yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The Ingress Controller then will route incoming traffic to your Apps with an [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # ingress-nginx specifix
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here is a Workflow from MS to install [ingress-nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) as Ingress Controller on your Cluster.

Comment: Right now I'm using a setup where I deploy a LoadBalancer for every Deployment. They all share the same ip and expose the pods port 80 on some different port. Than I use a VM with a reverse proxy & SSL determination (Caddy) for public access.

But the LoadBalancers are pretty expensive. Is there a simpler solution for my approach? Deploying another reverse proxy (nginx) seams pretty overloaded to me. And I'd need to route the traffic Path-Based. I'd rather stay with different ports.